# The probability of max n. of a trial

Tags: probability

In a dog farm, 35% of total dogs are black. The rest are brown dogs. What is the probably of having max. 3 brown dogs when randomly selecting 7 dogs from all the dogs.

I know how to calculate the probability of at least 3. But how to solve this one? Thank you!

Comment: Is the total number of dogs a large number?

Comment: @MattiP. Ah, yes, we don't know how many dogs in total. It just said, they randomly select 7 dogs from all dogs and what 's the percent of having max three brown dogs among those selected dogs (selected 7 dogs randomly)

Comment: The complementary event to "at most $3$" is "at least $4$" so if you can handle "at least" you can handle "at most".

Comment: In that case, I would model this as a repeated Bernoulli trial. We have a success probability of $p=1-0.35=0.65$ and we have 7 trials. Now
$$
P(X\leq 3) = 1- P(X>3)
$$

Comment: Thanks @Matti P. That's what I thought. But I was not sure. Thank you!

Comment: @lulu Thanks for your help! I tried to remove the possibility of all was brown, 6 were brown, 5 were brown, 4 were brown. But that's somehow too complicated.

Comment: So...what did you mean when you said you " know how to calculate the probability of at least $3$"?  Whatever method you have for doing that should work for "at least $4$" just as well.

Comment: @lulu, well 3 is not so big number. 4 or more are somehow too much :D. If they ask the max. 10, it takes a lot of time vs. 1- the possibility

Comment: Remember that you can always save some time by using a sum operator. For example, in this case, 
$$
P(X<5) = P(X=1)+P(X=2)+\ldots+P(X=5) = \sum_{k=1}^5 {7 \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{7-k}
$$
That's a single operation on the calculator; you have to press "enter" only once.

Comment: Thanks @Matti P.